# count on SQL only when the price is not 0,00

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the table like this :

```
ID  Price  ZONE
--  -----  ----
1   0,00    A
2   6,00    A
3   8,56    A
4   0,00    B
```

I want to show :

```
ZONE TOTAL
---- -----
A    2
B    0
```

How can I do that?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works too:

```
SELECT Zone, COUNT(NULLIF(Price,0)) AS Total FROM Table1 GROUP BY Zone
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `Price` is a text field:

```
select  zone
,       count(case when Price <> '0,00' then 1 end) as total
from    YourTable
group by
        zone
```

If price is a numeric field instead, replace `Price <> '0,00'` with `Price > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ZONE, COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE PRICE<> '0.00' GROUP BY ZONE
```

should do it

Comment: This won't return a row for `B`

Comment: Indeed, you're right, my statement does not what user609511 expects.
My mistake.